# Can ZOHO deluge script getUrl() function read HTTP response headers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, zoho, zoho-deluge

When trying to use `getUrl()` to grab a CSV file from a URL with basic .htaccess authorization, I am redirected to an Amazon S3 location. The `getURL()` function passes the original HTTP headers (for the auth) to Amazon S3 which Amazon thinks is an Amazon token; this causes the following error in the response:

> Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the `X-Amz-Algorithm` query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified

I can't see these issues talked about anywhere other than an advisory from Thompson Reuters: https://community.developers.thomsonreuters.com/questions/29247/aws-download-x-direct-download-returns-invalid-arg.html

The fix is to receive the redirect back from the remote server, look at the response and pull out the new (redirected) URL and grab the CSV file from there without the auth details in the header.

Is there a way in deluge script ZOHO to do this? The getUrl() function seems really basic and the documentation is very thin.

The other way to do this is a 'middleware' application that can use CURL, save the CSV's on a remote server then use ZOHO `getUrl()` to pull these CSV files. This is not an optimal solution but unless ZOHO gives access to some HTTP client functions then I don't see another way.

Answer (score 1):

To get the detail of the response headers include `detailed:true` in the invokeurl request.

###### Example:

```
// parameters is a Map
// header is a Map

response = invokeurl
[
    url :url
    type :POST
    parameters:parameters
    headers:header
    detailed:true
];

// To see all headers and content
info response;

// To see the http response code
info response.get('responseCode');

// With detailed:true any html or json returned will be put in responseText
// info response.get('responseText');

// To see the all http response headers
info response.get('responseHeader');

// To see a specific http response header
// Note: case matters in the response headers name
// "Content-Type" won't find "content-type"
info response.get('responseHeader').get('content-type');

// was the url redirected to another url?
info response.get('responseHeader').get('location');

// get the redirect url
redirect_url = response.get('responseHeader').get('location')
```

from there you can process the redirect url and pass it to the next http request.

###### Recommendation:

After working for months both including `detailed:true` and not including it, I now lean toward **always** including it.  `detailed:true` includes more useful information and has a helpful regular structure: `{responseCode: <code>, responseHeaders: <headers>, responseText: <returned-data>}`.

Comment: I don't believe this was possible at the time of asking. Inspecting the headers wasn't an option. Glad to see it's getting better with age.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Deluge using the invoke URL task - https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/web-data/invokeurl-task.html#response.

invokeURL can hand over the response headers to you from which you can get the redirect URL and then proceed with the authentication.

Comment: The support team originally said this wasn't possible and the work was abandoned.

Comment: The solution to this would be one of a workaround. InvokeURL is now equipped with features to read response headers. So, the solution would possibly be to hit the request and fail. Have the required headers read from the response (if Amazon sends back the response headers even for a 400 response). And then initiate a second request to the redirect URL if that helps. It would also be helpful if you could provide more details on how the request is made, what is being sent back in the response to see if a second request can be made to the redirect URL.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I suggested to your support team who said this was not possible when I was working on this earlier in the year. The project has since been abandoned as your platform didn't support this OR your support team didn't know. This is highly typical of Zoho.

Comment: The feature to read response headers was out only in the last quarter of 2019. It might not have been achievable back then when you raised the question. And this update could possibly have been missed. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.